# Reading a Range of values in POI by passing cell address

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to read a range of Cell Values in an Excel file using Apache POI using the AreaReference API.
Seem to be running into runtime exceptions.

[Click here to see the image representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqzJO.png)

I tried with the below sample code,

```java
FileInputStream  fis =new FileInputStream(new File("testRange.xlsx")); 
XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);   
XSSFSheet sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(0);  
AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference(sheet.getSheetName() + "!B2:K2", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
CellReference[] crefs = (CellReference[]) areaReference.getAllReferencedCells();
for (int i=0; i<crefs.length; i++) {
    XSSFSheet s = workbook.getSheet(crefs[i].getSheetName());
    XSSFRow r = s.getRow(crefs[i].getRow());
    XSSFCell c = r.getCell(crefs[i].getCol());
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _Seem to be running into runtime exceptions._ Can you [edit] your question and post details of those exceptions? Are you getting `RuntimeException`? If you have a stack trace then please post the entire trace.